# Can't call getRandom in main driver Java

Tags: java

I have a getRandom method that gets a random integer from an array and return it, but somehow when I try calling the method in my driver, there is an error

"The method getRandom(int[]) in the type europeanroulette is not applicable for the arguments ()"

How would I make this work? I'm just trying to display the int generated by the getRandom method.

```
 public final int[] europeanroulette = {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};

// random number generated from the roulette
     public int getRandom(int[] europeanroulette){
         int winningnumber = new Random().nextInt(europeanroulette.length);
         return winningnumber;
     }
```

And this is from my driver:

```
int winningnumber = europeanroulette.getRandom();
        System.out.println("The winning number is" + winningnumber );
```

Comment: Your getRandom requires a array of int as argument. Whereas you are calling it without the argument

Comment: Well yes. You've defined a method that takes an `int[]` argument and you're not passing it an `int[]`. (How much do you know about method arguments (also known as parameters)?)

Comment: @Vwin Edited! Didn't include it in the code

Comment: method is static so why you are calling with reference europeanroulette??

Comment: You are calling getRandom on the array whereas its a memeber of the class in which you defined. Use getRandom(europeanroulette) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring the int[] in the class that contains the getRandom(), declare it in the driver, and pass the parameter into the method:

```
// random number generated from the roulette
 public static int getRandom(int[] nums){
     int winningnumber = nums[new Random().nextInt(nums.length)]; //using the number as index
     return winningnumber;
 }
```

in the driver:

```
public final int[] europeanroulette= {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};

int winningnumber = getRandom(europeanroulette);// or whatever class.getRandom(); (the class where your method is located in.)
System.out.println("The winning number is" + winningnumber );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns in error in the driver under "getRandom" as "The method getRandom(europeanroulette) is undefined for the type roulettedriver"

Comment: @PatrickBui make getRandom a static method,  then call it using TheClassName.getRandom(europeanroulette); obviously change TheClassName to whatever class the "getRandom" is in.

Comment: gives me the error "Cannot invoke getRandom(int[]) on the array type int[]"

Comment: @PatrickBui don't call the class and the variable the same name. Rename the int[] variable to "nums" and pass that into the method

Answer (score 3):

```
public int getRandom(int[] europeanroulette)
```

Get rid of the parameter. The class already provides its own array.

```
public int getRandom()
```

Comment: its better than passing array from different class.

Comment: @Prashant I wouldn't agree with your comment necessarily, because the method can be used for many purposes, being a utility method. I find it more clear if your pass in an array.

Comment: @JClassic Even if the method is in a class called `EuropeanRoulette`? It isn't the way I would design it, but given we are where we are ...

Comment: Is the class called europeanroulette or is that what the int[] is called?

Comment: The class is called europeanroulette AND the int[] is called europeanroulette

Answer (score 2):

call like below statement

```
int winningnumber = getRandom(europeanroulette);
```

1)  your method is static so if you are calling from same class then call directly if you are calling from another class then use `<class_name>.<method_name>;`

2) europeanroulette variable should be initialized in your driver class. then you can use and call the method `public int getRandom(int[] europeanroulette)`

Comment: Does not work unfortunately, "europeanroulette cannot be resolved as a variable"

Comment: @PatrickBui `europeanroulette`  define it in driver class(not where you have declared currently.) then you will not get error.

Comment: the method does not return an int[]

Comment: @JClassic : my mistake,i changed that. initially i thought he is returning an array so ihad given that. not its integer only.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something along these lines:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class EuropeanRoulette {
    private static Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static int getRandom(int[] numbers) {
        int selectedIndex = random.nextInt(numbers.length);
        return numbers[selectedIndex];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = { 0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26 };

        System.out.println(EuropeanRoulette.getRandom(numbers));
    }
}
```

`Random#nextInt(int bound)` will return the winning index, not the winning number itself.
That is why you return `numbers[selectedIndex]`.

Also, it is perfectly fine to provide `numbers` array as an argument, especially to a static function, since you would be expecting a stateless call.